# Vue3 displaying and hiding App components according to current view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Currently in my web app made in Vue3 I have the following app component:

```
<template>
  <CookieBanner/>
  <NavbarComponent/>
  <router-view />
  <FooterComponent/>
  <Toasts />
</template>

<script>
import NavbarComponent from '@/components/navbarComponent.vue'
import FooterComponent from '@/components/footerComponent.vue'
import CookieBanner from '@/components/cookieBanner.vue'
import Toasts from '@/components/toastsComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    CookieBanner,
    Toasts
  },
}
</script>
```

So as you can see, regardless of the active view, the components `CookieBanner`, `Navbar`, `Footer` and `Toasts` get rendered.

In some special cases, I would like to not render the Navbar and the Footer. What is the proper way of doing this?

All I can think of is adding a `v-if` in those components and calling a function `displayNavbar()` and `displayFooter()` that checks for the route and if it's one of the special ones that should not have it, returns `false`.

Is this the correct way or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I think you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/64951947/8172857

Comment: Finally I went with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352191/3770881 which is similar to what you said (using `meta` in the routes), but bit more clear for what I wanted to do